# Flex: Could not set spark datagrid selectedIndex property

Tags: datagrid, flex4.5, flex-spark

I am trying to set datagrid selectedIndex. selectedIndex value is based on some logic. In mx datagrid it was simple assigning value to selectedIndex property and was working fine but is not behaving similar in case of spark datagrid.

For example - *mygrid.selectedIndex = 1;* does not set the value to 1.

Answer (score 0):

In Flex 4.5 Application Default set Data grid selcted index is first row only. if you want to change a row selection Please Try this Method setSelectedCell();.